# setting state for the array which is inside the object in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do setState where I want to update the state in reactjs .

```
this.state = {
    activePage: 0,
    visible: false,
    questionType: null,
    form: {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        pages: [{
            title: '',
            description: '',
            questions: []
        }]

    }
};
```

This is the initial state and on every entry of data ,I want all those questions to be under questions array which we have in pages.
What I tried to do to achieve this ?

```
onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log('data is ', data);
    let newForm = {
        ...this.state.form
    };
    // it shows that we can't do this as it is not iterable 
    newForm.pages.questions = [...newForm.pages.questions, ...data];


    this.setState({
        newForm
    });



}
```

Comment: what is the type of `data`? Is that a single `question` object or an array of `question`s?

Answer (score 0):

This part of code cannot work as `pages` is an array. You have to provide the index of which page you want to modify.

`newForm.pages.questions=[...newForm.pages.questions,...data];`

Should be something like

`newForm.pages[indexOfPage].questions=[...newForm.pages[indexOfPage].questions,...data];`

Comment: it says invalid atempt to spred non iterable thing

Comment: That's probably because you are spreading the `data` object. Try with `newForm.pages[indexOfPage].questions=[...newForm.pages[indexOfPage].questions, data];`